# General error during conversion: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/groovy/grails/commons/ApplicationAttributes

Tags: grails

I am getting the following exception while running grails. Recently i have upgraded grails from version 2.x to 3.3.6. Please let me know what i am missing. Thanks General error during conversion: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/groovy/grails/commons/ApplicationAttributes

java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/groovy/grails/commons/ApplicationAttributes
        at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.convertUncaughtExceptionToCompilationError(CompilationUnit.java:1123)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToPrimaryClassNodes(CompilationUnit.java:1101)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:624)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:602)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:579)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:558)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.ApiGroovyCompiler.execute(ApiGroovyCompiler.java:174)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.ApiGroovyCompiler.execute(ApiGroovyCompiler.java:56)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.daemon.AbstractDaemonCompiler$CompilerWorkerAdapter.execute(AbstractDaemonCompiler.java:73)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.daemon.AbstractDaemonCompiler$CompilerWorkerAdapter.execute(AbstractDaemonCompiler.java:64)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.WorkerDaemonServer.execute(WorkerDaemonServer.java:29)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.daemon.AbstractDaemonCompiler$CompilerDaemonServer.execute(AbstractDaemonCompiler.java:91)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)

Answer (score 1):

This class was moved to `grails.core.ApplicationContext`, if it is in your code, so please update it to the new package. If it in the plugin seems that you need to update version or remove it(or you can upgrade it to grails 3 used docs)

Answer (score 1):

This bug during the groovy compilation process i.e

```
General error during instruction selection: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
```

could happen due to 3-4 things

1. A specific module that has the required dependency was not declared.
2. The dependency was declared but could have been declared with "implementation" in the build.gradle file rather than "api".
3. The dependency was declared but the compilation process may have gotten confused due to a mix of "compile" and "implementation" dependencies being simultaneously present on the compile classpath. It would be better to move all of them to the new gradle style and avoid 'compile' and 'testCompile' dependencies.
4. The compilation process has gotten confused due to some classes (of another module) being compiled with one version of a jar and some other classes being compiled with a more recent version. The best way would be to do a proper clean build of all modules.