# missing dependency org/codehaus/groovy/grails/commons/ApplicationAttributes

Tags: grails

I am getting the following error. Have grails 3.3.6 and trying to migrate 2.x application. Would appreciate any inputs

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Unable to load class grails.plugin.springsecurity.ui.AbstractS2UiController due to missing dependency org/codehaus/groovy/grails/commons/ApplicationAttributes
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.convertUncaughtExceptionToCompilationError(CompilationUnit.java:1123)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToPrimaryClassNodes(CompilationUnit.java:1101)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:624)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:602)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:579)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:558)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.ApiGroovyCompiler.execute(ApiGroovyCompiler.java:174)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.ApiGroovyCompiler.execute(ApiGroovyCompiler.java:56)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.daemon.AbstractDaemonCompiler$CompilerWorkerAdapter.execute(AbstractDaemonCompiler.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.daemon.AbstractDaemonCompiler$CompilerWorkerAdapter.execute(AbstractDaemonCompiler.java:64)
    at org.gradle.workers.internal.WorkerDaemonServer.execute(WorkerDaemonServer.java:29)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.daemon.AbstractDaemonCompiler$CompilerDaemonServer.execute(AbstractDaemonCompiler.java:91)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [General error during conversion: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/groovy/grails/commons/ApplicationAttributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51644456/general-error-during-conversion-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-codehaus-gr)

Comment: You are right, @doelleri

Answer (score 1):

This class was moved to grails.core.ApplicationContext. You need to use the latest version of the plugin

**Btw, please, do not create a two topics, just update old one!**